# Is no HQL needed for Get, Update, Insert and Delete operations in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

Are Get/Update/Insert/Delete all built in functions that work out of the box without having to write any HQL?

I guess it gets this information from the mappings XML files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. These are primitive operations provided by ISession. HQL is only needed for complex queries.

Comment: for complex queries, i´d prefer using the criteria API though. At least it feels more comfortable to use to a c# programmer than SQL imho

Comment: I also use criteria whenever I can. But HQL is actually more powerful and could be precompiled.